# Creating a data.frame with a new row for each iteration

Tags: json, r, loops, lapply

I'm trying to make a script to run through a list of ids to apply to an API call so that I can create a data.frame of results, where each result returned for each id called is a row.

```
library(jsonlite)
ids <- c("101","102","103")  
baseURL <- "http://api.example.com/query_json.ashx?m=Details&Id="
for (i in ids)  {   details <- lapply((paste(baseURL,i, sep="")), fromJSON) }
```

My problem is that it iterates through each id but then returns only the result from the last one (103). It's obvious there is quite a basic solution, but I'm missing it.

Comment: You keep overwriting `details`. You could replace the forloop with lapply or something similar.

Comment: you can try:  `lapply(ids, function(id) fromJSON(paste(baseURL,id, sep="")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, both suggestions worked.

Because the resulting `fromJSON` R list was nested, I needed to adapt my code further so that the eventual data frame was properly structured.

```
library(jsonlite)
ids <- c("101","102","103")  
nids <- length(ids)
baseURL <- "http://api.example.com/query_json.ashx?m=Details&Id="

details <- c()
for (i in ids)  {   
  details <- lapply(ids, function(id) fromJSON(paste(baseURL,id, sep="")))
}

details <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(details), nrow=nids, byrow=T))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try sth like that

```
ids <- c("101","102","103")  
baseURL <- "http://api.example.com/query_json.ashx?m=Details&Id="
details <- c()
for (i in ids)  {   
  details[i] <- lapply((paste(baseURL,i, sep="")), fromJSON)
}
df <- data.frame(details, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

First you put the results into vector and then create the data frame.